# select and arrange multiple result within single projection

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

Apologies for not having sample graph.

I’ve a directed acyclic graph mapping  where Multiple nodes called "greatgrandparents" have edges to "grandparents"  that has edges to multiple "parents" with edges to multiple "children".

Something like,

```
greatgrandparent1 -> grandparent1 -> parent1 -> child1
greatgrandparent1 -> grandparent1 -> parent1-> child2 
greatgrandparent1 -> grandparent1 -> parent2 -> child3 
greatgrandparent1 -> grandparent1 -> parent2 -> child4
```

…
So on …

I am starting from grandparent, walking up to connected greatgrandparent.
Also walking down from grandparent to parent and then to connected children’s.

I need a query that will return something like below.

```
{‘greatgrandparent’:  ‘greatgrandparent1’ , ‘parent’ : ‘parent1’ , ‘children’ : '['child1', 'child2', …..]'}
{‘greatgrandparent’:  ‘greatgrandparent1’ , ‘parent’ : ‘parent2’ , ‘children’ : '['child3', 'child4', …..]'}
…..
```

….

So far I am able to get  each child on separate line like this,

```
{‘greatgrandparent’:  ‘greatgrandparent1’ , ‘grandparent’ : ‘grandparent1’, ‘parent’ : ‘parent1’ , ‘children’ : ‘child1’}
{‘greatgrandparent’:  ‘greatgrandparent1’  ‘grandparent’ : ‘grandparent1’, ,‘parent’ : ‘parent1’ , ‘children’ : ‘child2’}
{‘greatgrandparent’:  ‘greatgrandparent1’  ‘grandparent’ : ‘grandparent1’,  ‘parent’ : ‘parent2’ , ‘children’ : ‘child3’}
{‘greatgrandparent’:  ‘greatgrandparent1’  ‘grandparent’ : ‘grandparent1’,  ‘parent’ : ‘parent2’ , ‘children’ : ‘child4}
```

..

How can I get all children in a list?
I am using amazon Neptune with gremlin_python.

```
g.V()
.has('grandparent', 'name', 'grandparent1’).as_(‘grandparent')
.repeat(timeLimit(1000).in()).until(hasLabel('greatgrandparent'))
.dedup().order().by('name').as_(‘greatgrandparent')
.select('grandparent').repeat(timeLimit(1000).out()).until(hasLabel(‘parent))
.dedup().order().by('name').as_(‘parent')
.repeat(timeLimit(1000).out()).until(hasLabel('children'))
.dedup().order().by('name').as_(‘children')
.select(‘greatgrandparent’,grandparent','parent', 'children').by(‘name’)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to investigate use of `path` and `group`. To simulate the relationships (g-grandparent, grandparent, parent, children) I'm going to use airports from the air-routes data set. First of all lets look at a simple use of `path` starting from `ZKE` which will be playing the role of our great grandparent.

```java
g.V().has('code','ZKE').
  repeat(out().simplePath()).
  times(3).
  path().
    by('code')
```

when run we get

```
1   path[ZKE, YFA, YMO, YKQ]
2   path[ZKE, YFA, YMO, YTS]
```

In order to preserve this relationship, but fold the children into a list, we can add a `group..by` to the query.

```
g.V().has('code','ZKE').
  repeat(out().simplePath()).
  times(3).
  path().
    by('code').
  group().
    by(limit(local,3)).
    by(tail(local).fold())
```

which gives us

```
1   {('ZKE', 'YFA', 'YMO'): ['YKQ', 'YTS']}
```

Perhaps using these building blocks you can achieve the results you are looking for,

Comment: thanks for the response. that gets me closer. However, I have requirement where I need to select specific item from the key. So for example above I need to select 'YMO' or in some cases 'YFA'. is there a way to access local collection by position or by some suffix. e.g. 'YMO-somesuffix'. Is it possible to only have key element by either position or suffix.  or filter first by() based on some attribute? thanks.

Comment: something like `group().by(limit(select(local).where(label().is(eq('mylabel')),3)).by(tail(local).fold())`

Comment: What would you want the final result to look like in the case where you select 'YMO' ?

Comment: just omit other members of the key , tail end stays as is- so something like  => {( 'YMO'): ['YKQ', 'YTS']}  -thx.

Comment: OK I'll think about that. It might be doable - but the Gremlin might get a bit ugly!

Comment: Also would you want to group and then reduce the key, or reduce the key before grouping, so in fact the group key now becomes 'YMO' - which might pick up more children.

Comment: Either way is fine. Main items here are e.g. 'YMO'  rest of the keys are redundant. For values all Children however are important, so they need to be correct. is local collection selectable? that will make life much easier.

Comment: You can select locally using `range` , `tail`, and `limit` if you know the index. If you don't know the index it gets trickier. This is likely to be a lot easier using TinkerPop Gremlin version 3.7.1 which added 20 or so new string and list manipulation steps to Gremlin. Once the database you are using supports those, things get a lot easier. I will see if I can add an example of selecting locally using the pre 3.7.1 steps.